# Objective C: Function returning correct data for the first time of call and null for other times

Tags: objective-c, function, memory-management, nsstring

Am a beginner in objective C, i am implementing a function that would query a web server and display the returning string in console. I am calling the function (getDatafromServer) repeatedly in a loop. The problem is that the first time am getting the value whereas the other times, it returns me a (null) in console... I've searched about memory management and check out on the forums but none have worked. Can you please guys tell me where am wrong in the codes below? Thanks in advance....

```
@implementation RequestThread

+(void)startthread:(id)param{

 while (true) {
  //NSLog(@"Test threads");
  sleep(5);
  NSLog(@"%@",[self getDatafromServer]);
 }

}

+(NSString *) getDatafromServer{

 NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

 NSString *myRequestString = @"name=Hello%20&email=essssss@live.com";

 NSData *myRequestData = [NSData dataWithBytes:[myRequestString UTF8String] length:[myRequestString length]];

 NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://192.168.1.32/gs/includes/widget/getcalls.php?user=asdasd&passw=asdasdasd"]];
 [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
 [request setHTTPBody: myRequestData];
 [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];
 NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];

 NSString *myString = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[returnData bytes]];

 [myRequestString release];
 [request release];
 [returnData release];

 return myString;
 [pool release];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a problem with the autorelease pool.  Firstly, as Nickolay has said, the release never happens because it is after the return.  I'm amazed you aren't seeing compiler warnings.  Make sure you have `-Wall` set in "other warning flags" and you have the "Run static analyzer" build option set.

Since you want to use the returned string outside of the function, the autorelease pool must also be outside the function, or the string may be deallocated before your log gets to it.  Your code structure should look more like:

```
+(void)startthread:(id)param
{

    while (true) 
    {
        NSAutoreleasePool* pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
        //NSLog(@"Test threads");
        sleep(5);
        NSLog(@"%@",[self getDatafromServer]);
        [pool drain]; // use instead of release in case you move to GC
    }
}
```

The other problem you have is that you are not doing any error checking.  How can you be sure that:

- the request to the server is working?
- the response from the server is encoded as UTF-8.

You need to check if returnData is nil after you get it and you need to examine the NSError if it is.  So you need something like this:

```
NSError* error = nil;
NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:&error];
if (returnData == nil)
{
    the error object will be set and contain useful info.
}
```

You also need to check if myString is nil.  If it is, it will be because the response was not encoded as UTF-8.  With HTTP the default encoding is not UTF-8, it is ISO-8859-1.  Also, the body of the response might not be character data at all.  You need to examine the response to find out how to decode the data.  So the code snippet I posted above should really look like:

```
NSError* error = nil;
NSURLResponse* response = nil;
NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
if (returnData == nil)
{
    // the error object will be set and contain useful info.
}
else
{
    // You can get the content type and encoding from the response here.
}
```

**Edit**

Also, your code violates the [Memory Management Rules](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000994-BAJHFBGH).  You did not obtain `myRequestString` or `returnData` through alloc, copy or new, neither have you retained them, so you **must not** release them.

Comment: Hi JeremyP, thanks for your answer... I've changed the codes but the result is nealy the same: Except that before i used to get the value for the first iteraction and now am getting for the first and 8th.... I guess we are on the right path... The response from the server is UTF8, i correctly set it before.. IF i use the function once, it works well, but on the second or more calls it wont function well....

Answer (score 1):

That's bad idea to use autorelease pool in this function, and release it after 'return'.
Remove pool and everything should be ok.

Comment: The `[pool release]` call is located after the return, so the pool is leaked as the call is never made. But I also think that the creation / destruction of an `AutoreleasePool` is not a good idea here.

Comment: @Sylvain: Actually, the method is called repeatedly inside an infinite loop, so in fact, you **must** have an autorelease pool (in the ref counted environment) or you'll run out of memory.  It's in the wrong place here, of course.

Comment: @JeremyP: I agree with you, what I wanted to say is that the handling of the autorelease pool should not have been done in the `getDatafromServer` method, but in the loop in the `startthread` method.

Comment: Hi all,thanks for your replies... even though placed the codes from the getDatafromServer in the loop, it gives me the same result. The first iteration gives me the correct values, whereas the others give me: (null). Any ideas over this?

Comment: @Sylvain: Yes, I've put it in my answer.

Comment: Hi JeremyP, thanks for your answer... I've changed the codes but the result is nealy the same: Except that before i used to get the value for the first iteraction and now am getting for the first and 8th.... I guess we are on the right path... The response from the server is UTF8, i correctly set it before.. IF i use the function once, it works well, but on the second or more calls it wont function well....

Comment: Thanks JememyP, it was the page itself....i set it UTF8, but my friend replaced the file by another...and you know the rest.... Thanks Nickolay also... you guys helped!